# Copy paste on summer-note editor from word doc with bullets and number does not show bullets and number - IE and Mozila

Tags: jquery, angularjs, summernote

When i copy and paste content from word document to even online summer note editor it does not display bullets and numbers in any browser. It is actually outdent content and manually i have to indent it to view bullets.

But it also work in chrome only.

To workaround it, i have added onPaste event on summer-note editor and prevent default paste event, take copied content and in form of html i just paste in summer-note but it only resolved in chrome for other browser it is not working.

**IE** version : 11.0.9600 (First bullet displayed small)
**Firefox** version : 59.0.1-32 bit.

Online Summer-note editor link : 
https://summernote.org/

Sample code of on paste function which only works on chrome but in IE there is no way to get html content from clipboard:

```
$scope.pasteData = function(e) {

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
msie = msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);

var ffox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
var htmlContent;

if(msie){

    if( e.clipboardData ){

        htmlContent = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, htmlContent);
        e.preventDefault();

    }
    else if( window.clipboardData ){

        // In case of IE e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'); is not work

    }

}
else{

    htmlContent = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/html');

    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, htmlContent);

    e.preventDefault();

}
}
```